# How to access different XML nodes which have same parent?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, xmldocument

I have a XML file like this:

```
<Document>
   <Tests>
      <Test>
          <Name>A</Name>
          <Value>1</Value>
      </Test>
      <Test>
          <Name>A</Name>
          <Value>2</Value>
      </Test>
      <Test>
          <Name>B</Name>
          <Value>10</Value>
      </Test>
      <Test>
          <Name>B</Name>
          <Value>20</Value>
      </Test>
   </Tests>
</Document>
```

I made a class to hold data for each `Test` node:

```
public class TestData
{
public string TestName {get; set;}
public float TestValue {get; set;}
}
```

And I read the data using XPATH like this (`ztr` is instance of `XmlDocument` And I already know the name of `Test` I am going to read, since it was populted into a ListView):

```
    public TestData GetTestData(string testName)
    {
        TestData data = new TestData();           

        data.TestName = testName;
        data.TestValue = float.Parse(ztr.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test[Name = '" + testName + "')]/Value").InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return data;
    }
```

**Now, te problem is** that if I want to make a list of data as `List<TestData>` each TestData only refers to the first occurance of the Test node in the XML file. What I mean is lets imagin I have a ListView that is already populated by name of all `Test` nodes in my xml file. that is something like this in this case:

`ListView = A,A,B,B` and then I copy all names to a string[] array

And I use this code to read them all in one go:

```
private List<TestData> GetAllData()
{
    List<TestData> Datas = new List<TestData>();
    TestData data;

    foreach(string test in stringOfNames)
    {
       data = new TestData;
       data = GetTestData(test);
       Datas.add(data);
    }

    return Datas
}
```

**As I told you** This code does not make any distinguish between different `Test`. It just returns the first occurance of a `Test` so the result for `GetAllData()` will be:

```
Name     Value
A        1
A        1
B        10
B        10
```

**BUT I want it to be like**

```
Name     Value
A        1
A        2
B        10
B        20
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? and how to solve this problem?

P.S. I wrote all the codes just here in stackoverflow...they are not compiled, just imagine they work fine :D

Comment: So... you want the accumulated Values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify your `GetTestData()` method** (and its caller accordingly):

```
    public TestData GetTestData(string testName, int pos) 
    { 
        TestData data = new TestData();            

        data.TestName = testName; 
        data.TestValue 
         = float.Parse(
ztr.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Tests/Test[Name = '" + testName + "')][" + pos + "]/Value").InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

        return data; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `SelectSingleNode`, use [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.aspx) instead, your current xpath should suffice I think. You'll have to re-write your `GetTestData` method to handle iterating through the `XmlNodeList` to parse out the correct `float` value.